# drupal_redirect_form not working with entity

Tags: redirection

I have created custom submit form handler for entity using below

```
$form['#submit'][]='app_contact_form_submit_message_alter';
```

but when i used

```
drupal_get_messages($type = NULL);
drupal_set_message('Thanks for your feedback we will contact soon.');
drupal_redirect_form($form_state);
```

It redirect correctly but entity is not created.

and even if i use `drupal_goto()` same thing happening.

Comment: As side note, the name of the submission handler could potentially conflict with a hook implementation of `hook_form_FORMID_alter()` done for a form with ID equal to submit_message.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to redirect a form submit you should use the redirect parameter:

```
function app_contact_form_submit_message_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_get_messages($type = NULL);
  drupal_set_message('Thanks for your feedback we will contact soon.');
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'node/23'; // The path you want to go
}
```

This will call drupal_redirect_form($form_state) byt its self, if you call it directly you are skipping the save step.

More info: https://api.drupal.org/comment/18139#comment-18139